# Find the real parameter $\color{maroon}{a}$ such that the following functions...

Tags: functions

How would you solve this exercise?

Determine the values of $\color{teal}a$ for which the following functions:
$$\color{maroon}{f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}},\quad \color{violet} {f(x)=\ln x}$$
and
$$\color{maroon}{g:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{R} },\quad\color{violet}{g(x)={a\over x}}$$

have one common point.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would first sketch the graphs of both $f$ and $g$, and then I'd probably justify my answer by the IVT. The case $a>0$ is really simple (just look at the limits as $x \to 0+$ and $x \to +\infty$). The case $a<0$ requires more work.